# Override Minimum length string of Select2

Tags: jquery-select2

### Select2 Jquery Plugin

I was having hard time how to override the default message for minimum length input in jquery Select2.

by default the plugin gives the following message.

### Default Text

```
Please enter 1 more characters
```

My requirement was to show, the following text

### Required Text

```
Enter 1 Character
```

please share the solution. 
Thanks.

Comment: you can also use css if you just want to hide it completely:
`
.select2-results__option.select2-results__message {
  display: none;
}
`

Comment: I want to override text and not hide it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

---

### Solution

Here is the solution that i have found out.

### Prior to v4

#### Initialize

```
$("input[name='cont_responsible'],input[name='corr_responsible'],input[name='prev_responsible'],input[name='pfmea_responsible']").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            formatInputTooShort: function () {
                return "Enter 1 Character";
            },  
});
```

---

#### Note

Do not forget to add this code in your document. ready function.

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
});
```

I shared my solution, any better solutions are welcome.

Thanks.

### Using v4 and onwards

The following worked for V4. @Isaac Kleinman

`language: { inputTooShort: function () { return ''; } },`

Comment: Doesn't look like it.

Comment: This works for me in v4: `language: {
            inputTooShort: function () { return ''; }
        },`

Comment: Is it possible to alter when a select object was already initialized?

Answer (score 42):

The accepted answer does not work for Select2 v4. Expanding on the comment by @IsaacKleinman, the way to override the default messages for an individual Select2 instance is through the `language` property:

```js
var opts = {
  language: {
    inputTooShort: function(args) {
      // args.minimum is the minimum required length
      // args.input is the user-typed text
      return "Type more stuff";
    },
    inputTooLong: function(args) {
      // args.maximum is the maximum allowed length
      // args.input is the user-typed text
      return "You typed too much";
    },
    errorLoading: function() {
      return "Error loading results";
    },
    loadingMore: function() {
      return "Loading more results";
    },
    noResults: function() {
      return "No results found";
    },
    searching: function() {
      return "Searching...";
    },
    maximumSelected: function(args) {
      // args.maximum is the maximum number of items the user may select
      return "Error loading results";
    }
  }
};
$('#mySelect').select2(opts);
```

To override the functions globally, call the `set` function on the defaults ([according to the docs](https://select2.github.io/options-old.html#setting-default-options)):

```js
$.fn.select2.defaults.set("key", "value")
```

However, in our code we do it like this:

```js
$.fn.select2.defaults.defaults['language'].searching = function(){
  return 'Custom searching message'
};
```

I don't know why we don't follow the docs, but it works.

Comment: There's seems to be no documentation about language options. The only way to find them all is to look at the source

https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/src/js/select2/i18n/en.js

Comment: Thanks for the usefull data it helped me a lot. select2 documentation is really incomplete.

Answer (score 9):

You can try this on version 4.0 or higher
you can see reference for answer frome this link :
[issues reference](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2561)

```
$("#select2").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 1,
  language: {
    inputTooShort: function() {
        return 'Please Add More Text';
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using django-select2, just add attributes to your form in forms.py:

```
 widget=BookSelect2Widget(
            attrs={'data-minimum-input-length': 1}
            )
```

Answer (score -1):

Override the function behaviour like below

```
$.fn.select2.defaults = $.extend($.fn.select2.defaults, {
formatMatches: function(matches) {
    return matches + $filter('translate')('label.matches.found');
},
formatNoMatches: function() {
    return $filter('translate')('noMatches.found');
},
formatInputTooShort: function(input, min) {
    var n = min - input.length;
    return $filter('translate')('label.please.enter ') + n + $filter('translate')(' more.characters') + (n == 1 ? "" : "s");
},
formatInputTooLong: function(input, max) {
    var n = input.length - max;
    return $filter('translate')('please.delete ') + n + $filter('translate')('')('delete.characters') + (n == 1 ? "" : "s");
},
formatSelectionTooBig: function(limit) {
    return $filter('translate')('select.only') + limit + $filter('translate')('select.item ') + (limit == 1 ? "" : "s");
},
formatLoadMore: function(pageNumber) {
    return $filter('translate')('load.results');
},
formatSearching: function() {
    return $filter('translate')('label.search');
}
```

});
}